# Is LSTM suitable for forecasting stocks trend?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, lstm, forecasting

I'm very beginner in AI and want to find an AI algorithm for forecasting stocks trend, I've seen SLTM but these algorithms use the price of a share for example 1000 days and predicate the next day, I want a predicate based on multiple rules, for example, buyer power or volume or ratio between them, etc...

I've used the LSTM by the price of a share in input.
But as I mentioned I do not want to use time series of prices :
for example, I have some data same to the below:

2.3, 2.1, 2.8,1.05,....,3.5,1.08  ---> +5

1.5, 4.1, 3.8,2.47,....,1.2,2.41  ---> +2

.

.

.

2.2, 2.8, 2.1,1.35,....,2.6,1.18  ---> -3

That this data is the situation of a share in stock and have not the price and I want to fit the AI system with these millions of data and then with another sample of like share data forecast the trend of that share!
The important thing for me is figuring out the relation or pattern of inputs and the output of these data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is theoretically possible to forecast stock prices with LSTM. But...
The performance of LSTM for stock price prediction can vary depending on the quality and quantity of the data, as well as the specific architecture and parameters of the model.
In real-life it is not that effective in predicting long-term trends or sudden changes in the market because its impossible to factor all possible events that may really affect a price.

You can give it a try using this code:

https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/lstm-python-stock-market

Comment: Thanks for your answer
With this method, is it possible to find the relationship between the input and output data in such a way that the relationship is not sensitive to numbers and only depends on the relationship between them, for example, if we consider the input string as:

t1, t2, t3...,t100 -> o1 

Finally, the relationship between the inputs should be like the following relationships:

t1 to t3 is an upward trend AND 
t4/t5 is greater than 2 AND
ignore t6 to t15 AND....

Comment: Yes, generalization is the winning ticket if you can get it.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question - Yes

> Is LSTM suitable for forecasting stocks trend?

LSTMs can be used for time series forecasting, but if you want to use something more complex and better there are many alternatives including Transformers which tackle many problems encountered in LSTMs such as lack of parallelization ability.

If you want to use some more involved methods I recommend checking out:
https://timeseriesai.github.io/tsai/

Comment: Thanks danielstankw
But as I mentioned I do not want to use time series of prices :
for example, I have some data same to the below:
2.3, 2.1, 2.8,1.05,....,3.5,1.08  ---> +5
1.5, 4.1, 3.8,2.47,....,1.2,2.41  ---> +2
.
.
.
2.2, 2.8, 2.1,1.35,....,2.6,1.18  ---> -3
That this data is the situation of a share in stock and have not the price and I want to fit the AI system with these millions of data and then with another sample of like share data forecast the trend of that share!   
The important thing for me is figuring out the relation or pattern of inputs and the output of these data